# How to understand network neural network architecture from a research paper

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Hello everyone I have the following architecture from the DELP-DAR research paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865519303216)

[image: network architecture]

and I dont really understand two things, first how can you go from 960x570 size to 481x286 with a 3x3 convolution? Does this mean I have to have asymmetric padding or what?

Second, what is the value after a slash? 3 x 3 / 2 - i though it to be stride but then you cant have a stride of 2 and end up with output of the same dimensions as the input.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I figured it out with the help of some micro-chart I didn't notice earlier. conv 1x1/1 is a layer with the input from the prev layer( lets call it x), the conv 3x3/2 is another layer with the input from the same 'x', while the conv 3x3/1 is a layer stacked on the conv 1x1/1, the outputs from 3x3/1 and 3x3/2 are then concatenated.